# Aproximate maximum of two multivariate Gaussians with multivariate Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, estimators, approximation

Given two multivariate Gaussians $G_1(\mathbf{x}), G_2(\mathbf{x})$ (not PDFs!) with the same center at the coordinate origin and different covariance matrix $\mathbf{F}_1, \mathbf{F}_2$, where $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, \dots, x_M]^T$ present input vector:

$$
G_1(\mathbf{x}) = e^{-\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{F}_1 \mathbf{x}},\quad G_2(\mathbf{x}) =  e^{-\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{F}_2 \mathbf{x}}
$$

The two Gaussians are joined into new function H by getting maximum value of the two:

$$
 H(\mathbf{x}) = \max(G_1(\mathbf{x}), G_2(\mathbf{x}))
$$

At the last step I want to approximate function $H(\mathbf{x})$ with another Gaussian $G_{3}(\mathbf{x})$, so the $\mathbf{F}_3$ need to be estimated:

$$
G_3(\mathbf{x}) = e^{-\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{F}_3 \mathbf{x}} \approx H(\mathbf{x}) 
$$

The question is, is there closed from to compute covariance matrix $\mathbf{F}_3$  directly from $\mathbf{F}_1$ and $\mathbf{F}_2$?

The accuracy of the aproximation of $\mathbf{F}_3$ sholud only be in the ball-park of best estimation of $\mathbf{F}_3$, it is much more important to have closed form solution.

Comment: What you attempt to do sounds like trying to solve the wrong problem.  Could you give more context explaining why you want to do this?

Comment: @Xi'an - not probability density function, the Gaussians are not normalized

Comment: @JarleTufto I came across this problem when dealing with two vector estimators with multivariate gaussian distribution (same center), that I wanted to join. The difference to normal approaches where two Gaussians are multiplied, in my case each of the two estimators detects different sources of noise. 

So what I want is to merge Gaussians together with some kind of "OR" operation on probability distributions, but no such thing exists as far as I know.

Comment: @JarleTufto - part 2:

Then I came up with the idea to "max" probabilities together as max can be interpreted as "OR" - but max operation only makes sense if the Gaussians are not normalized. 

In the end, I want to do more stuff to the resulting distribution and Gaussians are nice to compute with, so an approximation of the resulting distribution with Gaussian is desired.

Hopefully, my explanation is satisfactory.

Comment: The reason why the Gaussian pdfs are unnormalised still escapes me.

Comment: Because I believe, that the important concept in my problem is the relative probability of arbitrary point p_i(x) to probability in the center p_i(c), where c represents the center vector. And if we set p_i(c)=1 (unnormalized Gaussian), the probability p_i(x) also becomes relative probability to the center, which is later "maxed" together. I may be wrong, but if I am please, show me a better way to merge 2 PDFs with the "OR" operation explained above. If my goal is not explained enough please tell me, so I can edit the post with a visual explanation.

Comment: I think I left out one more thing: the different sources of noise sources are correlated, but different experiments of estimators suppress noise in different directions. This is why I wanted to use the max operation instead of summation.